# Program or web services to search for a track among many online music vendors (iTunes Store, Amazon, Google Play, etc.)

Tags: music, search-engine

I am looking for a program or web services that can:

- search for a track among online music vendors (iTunes Store, Amazon, Google Play, Beatport, etc.). It would be a meta-search engine combining results from as many online music vendors as possible, just like http://torrentz.eu/ does with torrent search engines.

Ideally:

- display the length of the track
- display the price of the track on each platform where it is available
- display codec information (e.g. FLAC, 320 kbps MP3, 256 kbps AAC, etc)
- allow to preview the track
- allow to search for several track at once
- also look for websites that offer the track for free (since some of them might be legally, freely available)
- free

Comment: What do you want to be able to search on? Just artist and track name?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes at least artist and track name (could be even combined in just one field like when search on Google). Then the more fields the better: release year, remixer name, label, etc.